# fail-fast in cucumberjs, protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor, ui-automation, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

I added fail-fast to my cucumberOpts like below:

```
cucumberOpts: {
  require: [
  conf.paths.e2e + '/utilities/hooks.js', 
  ],
  format: 'pretty',
  'fail-fast': true
  },
```

I have all my tests in a path like this: C:/tests/*.feature

I run my tests like this: `protractor protractor.conf.js`

This works fine as in it will stop the tests as soon as there's an error. But I'm having these tests run in a CI server like Bamboo and I was hoping to give rapid feedback while continuing to run the rest of the tests on faillure.

So if I have `4 tests in total`, `if the first test fails`, `I want to fail-fast on that first test` then `I want to continue running the other 3 tests/feature files`.

What it is doing now, which I don't like, is it will fail as soon as one test fails and it will NOT run any of the other feature files.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a problem with the protractor 4 version.

Could you downgrade to version protractor 3.3.0 and check if it is working as expected?

Some issues are in protractor, cucumberjs and other repositories:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/643
- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3491
- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3553
- https://github.com/mattfritz/protractor-cucumber-framework/issues/56
- https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-allure/issues/3

I will hope that they will fix the problem as soon as possible in next releases.

Comment: Downgrading didn't work either; is it working for you at v3.3.0? Are the rest of your tests still running even after a previous test failed-fast?

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas/clues I'm still struggling with not being able to run the rest of my other features after a previous feature failed with fail-fast = true; this is blocking proper reporting on our CI server and without that flag the e2e tests are taking a very long time even with multicapabilities (parallel)